# increasing json limit in upload to play framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am using play framework v2.5 (Java API).  In a post handler, I am getting the following exception (which leads me to believe it could be related to the size of the json data coming through).  I have added the following to the top of the controller action but that has not solved the issue:

```
@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Json.class, maxLength = 1024 * 1024 * 10 * 10)
```

Is there another config (perhaps setup in the application.conf file) or elsewhere whereby I can increase the size limit permitted for this post request to be handled.  I am using the Java API.

```
17:01:23.603 43598 [New I/O worker #3] RequestBodyHandler ERROR - Exception caught in RequestBodyHandler
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:433) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:128) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:99) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:725) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.doEncode(OneToOneEncoder.java:71) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:59) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.handleDownstream(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:88) ~[netty-http-pipelining-1.1.4.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.NettyResultStreamer$.sendDownstream(NettyResultStreamer.scala:182) ~[play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.core.server.netty.NettyResultStreamer$.play$core$server$netty$NettyResultStreamer$$nettyStreamIteratee(NettyResultStreamer.scala:140) ~[play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.core.server.netty.NettyResultStreamer$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$NettyResultStreamer$$send$1$1.streamEnum$1(NettyResultStreamer.scala:79) ~[play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.core.server.netty.NettyResultStreamer$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$NettyResultStreamer$$send$1$1.apply(NettyResultStreamer.scala:86) ~[play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.core.server.netty.NettyResultStreamer$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$NettyResultStreamer$$send$1$1.apply(NettyResultStreamer.scala:60) ~[play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.link(Promise.scala:304) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.linkRootOf(Promise.scala:289) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:253) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be using **play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer**
in application.conf to increase the data limit.  I will update the post when I get it to work.

One can use the following fields in the application.conf file to modify various buffers in play framework:

```
parsers.text.maxLength=
play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer=
play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=
```

Increasing the buffer sized resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

FYI the built in body parsers are covered here:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaBodyParsers#max-content-length

so you can use `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer` or define it in your action:

```
def save = Action(parse.maxLength(1024 * 10, storeInUserFile)) {  request =>
  Ok("Saved the request content to " + request.body)
}
```